# ComboBox no extrae bien el valor del ValueMember c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, combobox

Tengo un combo que extrae valores de una base de datos, el `DataSource` es:

```
    public List<Paciente> listaPacientes()
    {
        List<Paciente> lista = new List<Paciente>();

        if (this.cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            this.cn.Open();
        }

        String consulta = "select idpacientes, concat(nombre, ' ', apellido) as NombreCompleto, rut, correo from pacientes";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, this.cn);

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Paciente autFill = new Paciente()
            {
                IDPACIENTE = Convert.ToInt32(reader["idpacientes"]),
                NOMBRECOMPLETO= reader["NombreCompleto"].ToString(),
                RUTPACIENTE = reader["rut"].ToString(),
                CORREOPACIENTE = reader["correo"].ToString()
            };
            lista.Add(autFill);
        }
        this.cn.Close();

        return lista;
    }
```

la información del combo la cargo así:

```
    private void actualizarCombo()
    {

        var dataAccess = new Paciente();
        var paciente = dataAccess.listaPacientes();

        this.cmbPaciente.ValueMember = "idpacientes";
        this.cmbPaciente.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
        this.cmbPaciente.DataSource = paciente;


    }
```

Luego cuando extraigo el valor del `ValueMember`para poder mostrar la información del paciente en pantalla, el valor extraído no es lo esperado, es decir, en vez de obtener el numero de Id (`idpacientes`), obtengo el namespace del mismo.

Probé a cambiar la información así:

```
    private void actualizarCombo()
    {

        var dataAccess = new Paciente();
        var paciente = dataAccess.listaPacientes();

        this.cmbPaciente.ValueMember = "NombreCompleto";
        this.cmbPaciente.DisplayMember = "idpacientes";
        this.cmbPaciente.DataSource = paciente;           
    }
```

y al hacerlo, en el `displayMember` sigue el problema, de donde deduzco que puede ser un problema de la variable o campo `idpacientes`la cual la tengo declarada como int.

Espero su ayuda por favor.

---

Edición (Añado la clase `Paciente` que me solicitaron):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Fichas_Clinicas.Acceso_Datos;
using Fichas_Clinicas.Negocios;
using System.Data;

namespace Fichas_Clinicas.Negocios
{
    class Paciente
    {
        private int idPaciente;
        private String nombrePaciente;
        private String apellidoPaciente;
        private String rutPaciente;
        private String correoPaciente;
        private String sexoPaciente;
        private DateTime fechaNacPaciente;
        private String ocupacionPaciente;
        private String telefonoPaciente;
        private DateTime fechaRegPaciente;
        private String nombreCompleto;
        private PacienteBD pacBD;


        //******constructores*****
        //constructor vacio
        public Paciente()
        {

        }
        //constructor para guardar todo
        public Paciente(String _nombrePaciente, String _apellidoPaciente, String _rutPaciente, String _correoPaciente, String _sexoPaciente, DateTime _fechaNacPaciente, String _ocupacionPaciente, String _telefonoPaciente, DateTime _fechaRegPaciente)
        {
            this.nombrePaciente = _nombrePaciente;
            this.apellidoPaciente = _apellidoPaciente;
            this.rutPaciente = _rutPaciente;
            this.correoPaciente = _correoPaciente;
            this.sexoPaciente = _sexoPaciente;
            this.fechaNacPaciente = _fechaNacPaciente;
            this.ocupacionPaciente = _ocupacionPaciente;
            this.telefonoPaciente = _telefonoPaciente;
            this.fechaRegPaciente = _fechaRegPaciente;
        }

        //Constructor para actualizar
        public Paciente(Int32 _idPaciente, String _nombrePaciente, String _apellidoPaciente, String _rutPaciente, String _correoPaciente, String _sexoPaciente, DateTime _fechaNacPaciente, String _ocupacionPaciente, String _telefonoPaciente, DateTime _fechaRegPaciente)
        {
            this.idPaciente = _idPaciente;
            this.nombrePaciente = _nombrePaciente;
            this.apellidoPaciente = _apellidoPaciente;
            this.rutPaciente = _rutPaciente;
            this.correoPaciente = _correoPaciente;
            this.sexoPaciente = _sexoPaciente;
            this.fechaNacPaciente = _fechaNacPaciente;
            this.ocupacionPaciente = _ocupacionPaciente;
            this.telefonoPaciente = _telefonoPaciente;
            this.fechaRegPaciente = _fechaRegPaciente;
        }
        //Constructor de 1 argumento, para eliminar por ID
        public Paciente(Int32 _idPaciente)
        {
            this.idPaciente = _idPaciente;
        }



        //metodos setter y getter
        public int IDPACIENTE
        {
            get
            { return idPaciente; }
            set { idPaciente = value; }
        }

        public String NOMBREPACIENTE
        {
            get 
            { return nombrePaciente; }
            set { nombrePaciente = value; }
        }

        public String APELLIDOPACIENTE
        {
            get
            { return apellidoPaciente; }
            set { apellidoPaciente = value; }
        }

        public String RUTPACIENTE
        {
            get
            { return rutPaciente; }
            set { rutPaciente = value; }
        }

        public String CORREOPACIENTE
        {
            get
            { return correoPaciente; }
            set { correoPaciente = value; }
        }

        public String SEXOPACIENTE
        {
            get
            { return sexoPaciente; }
            set { sexoPaciente = value; }
        }

        public DateTime FECHANACPACIENTE
        {
            get
            { return fechaNacPaciente; }
            set { fechaNacPaciente = value; }
        }

        public String OCUPACIONPACIENTE
        {
            get
            { return ocupacionPaciente; }
            set { ocupacionPaciente = value; }
        }

        public String TELEFONOPACIENTE
        {
            get
            { return telefonoPaciente; }
            set { telefonoPaciente = value; }
        }

        public DateTime FECHAREGPACIENTE
        {
            get
            { return fechaRegPaciente; }
            set { fechaRegPaciente = value; }
        }

        public String NOMBRECOMPLETO
        {
            get
            { return nombreCompleto; }
            set { nombreCompleto = value; }
        }



        //llamados a funciones CRUD

        public void insertarPaciente()
        {
            pacBD = new PacienteBD(this);
            pacBD.insertarPaciente();
        }

        public void actualizarPaciente()
        {
            pacBD = new PacienteBD(this);
            pacBD.actualizarPaciente();
        }

        public void eliminarPaciente()
        {
            pacBD = new PacienteBD(this);
            pacBD.eliminarPaciente();
        }

        public List<Paciente> listaPacientes()
        {
   pacBD = new PacienteBD(this);
            return pacBD.listaPacientes();
        }
```

Comment: estas trabajando sobre winforms?

Comment: El orden es el incorrecto, primero llena tu datasource, luego el displayMember y finalmente ValueMember.

Comment: Podrías indicar la clase ´Paciente´ ?, veo que tienes los nombre de las propiedades en Mayúscula??

Comment: @RamiroBarone Si, sobre Winforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu **ComboBox** está recibiendo como `DataSource` un objeto del tipo `List<Paciente>`, así que debes asignar a las propiedades `ValueMember` y `DisplayMember` los nombres de las propiedades de la clase `Paciente`:

```
    //metodos setter y getter
    public int IDPACIENTE
    {
        get { return idPaciente; }
        set { idPaciente = value; }
    }

    public String NOMBREPACIENTE
    {
        get { return nombrePaciente; }
        set { nombrePaciente = value; }
    }
```

Prueba de esta manera:

```
private void actualizarCombo()
{

    var dataAccess = new Paciente();
    var paciente = dataAccess.listaPacientes();

    this.cmbPaciente.ValueMember = "IDPACIENTE";
    this.cmbPaciente.DisplayMember = "NOMBRECOMPLETO";
    this.cmbPaciente.DataSource = paciente;           
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, es la respuesta correcta. Te agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que llenar el datasource para elimentar el combobox:

```
private void actualizarCombo()
    {

        var dataAccess = new Paciente();
        var paciente = dataAccess.listaPacientes();

        this.cmbPaciente.DataSource = paciente;           
        this.cmbPaciente.ValueMember = "NombreCompleto";
        this.cmbPaciente.DisplayMember = "idpacientes";
    }
```

Prueba esta modificación y nos comentas.

Comment: Con esa modificación el combo no me muestra nada.

Comment: recuerda dar una respuesta correcta y no que pruebe a ver si funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Debes realizar algunas correcciones:

1- Hacer override a toString() en tu clase Paciente

```
public class Paciente
{
  public string Nombre {get;set;}
  public int id {get;set;}

}
public override string ToString()
{
    return Nombre;
}
```

2- Simplificar tu código, si tenes un metodo que te trae un listado, no es necesario pasar ese listado a una var para luego pasar esa var al ComboBox

```
private void actualizarCombo()
{        
  this.cmbPaciente.DataSource = dataAccess.listaPacientes();
}
```

3- Debes usar una propiedad del combo box

```
Paciente paciente = (Paciente )cmbPaciente.SelectedItem;
```

luego puedes usar las propiedades, id y Nombre

```
paciente.Nombre
paciente.id
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Recuerda dar una respuesta correcta y no que pruebe a ver si funciona.

Comment: la mía es correcta. funciona perfectamente en una muestra que hice. Yo no lo mande a hacer una prueba y me comente como le fue.

Comment: El usuario dice lo contrario.

Comment: a tu respuesta le falto, explicación.

Comment: Con lo que se describió, era más que suficiente.